# How I can convert web view to bitmap including all web view content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, bitmap

I'm using this function, it's working but give me only screenshot so if the web view more than page I can't get all content in bitmap

```
  public Bitmap createBitmapFromView(View v) {

    v.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    v.draw(c);
    return bitmap;
}
```